# High chart not showing accurate percentage for two curves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using line chart from high charts collection having two series to show information. These list are having integer value.I am using

```
spline: { stacking:'percent'}
```

to show graph in 0% to 100%.
I have a problem that i am not able to show accurate percentage for both series using this function.Only one series show data according to percentage.Other curve is always at 100%.
I have created a jsfiddle for this issue :- http://jsfiddle.net/9Yjc4/
Any suggesion would be appreciable.

Comment: When stacking like that, Highcharts defines 100% as the sum of both values. Then the two values always stack on top of each other, thats why the upper bar is always at 100%. See this example to maybe understand it better http://jsfiddle.net/8HsS7/. What do you want to achieve and what should be your 100%? Maybe use more realistic values instead of the weather example.

Comment: You are right. But is there any way to solve this problem so that i show information according to percentage from 0,0 co-ordinate for both  series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `compare: 'percent'`, not stacking. See: http://jsfiddle.net/9Yjc4/1/

Note: Highstock is required for comparing.